# Why does VS code shows output with weird symbols?

Tags: visual-studio-code, lua, output

I think this became a problem after installing extensions, but I'm not sure.

> [image: screenshot]

I tried reinstalling Visual Studio Code and removing settings synchronization, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In settings under Terminal > Integrated: Renderer Type, it defaults to "auto" which in my case selects the "canvas" setting. If you switch this to "dom" it will fix the jumbled letters in the integrated terminal.

Also i'd recommend double-checking your language packs that are installed in windows and either reinstall them or make sure you have installed correctly.

Hope this helps.